# GAE downloaded file extensions from blobstore

Tags: internet-explorer, google-app-engine, google-chrome, http-headers, blobstore

I'm currently storing a bunch of .docx files in the GAE Blobstore. I recently noticed that these files are downloading without file extensions on some computers (IE 9 for Windows 7), but works fine for others (IE 8, Chrome for Windows 7).

Here's how the files are stored in the blobstore:

```
f = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                           _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=filename)
## then some code to write data and save ##
```

Here's the response headers for the file from the Chrome inspector:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="causes_of_ww1_emanresu"
Content-Length:12120
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Date:Fri, 26 Oct 2012 23:54:09 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars:$0.000033
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage:ms=15 cpu_ms=0
```

Here's how I serve the blob:

```
self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=blob_info.filename, content_type=blob_info.content_type)
```

I even tried hardcoding `content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'` to no avail.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it?

---

As requested, here's how I get the file information when initially saving the blob. I'm  pretty certain that the error is not occuring at this level, but here's the precursor to the problem:

```
# get the file from a file_url with urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch(file_url)
headers = result.headers

# some custom functions to return a filename
username = self.get_username()
filename = get_filename(title, username)

# write the file to blobstore
f = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=headers['content-type'], 
                           _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=filename)
with files.open(f, 'a') as data:
    data.write(result.content)
files.finalize(f)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(f)
```

Comment: How are you sending the blob back? send_blob?

Comment: Yep, I'm using `self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=blob_info.filename)`

Comment: Can you post the code that actually computes the `filename`, to be sure it has the extension. Also, can you check using the BlobInfo that the filename is stored with the right extension.

Comment: Sure, I just added the source of the file information. And I've checked BlobInfo, the `content_type` is correct.

Comment: I just realized what you were asking... no the `filename` doesn't include the file extension ('doc1' vs 'doc1.docx'). I assumed that the `content_type` header would take care of this (as it works fine on most browsers). Would this be the source of the problem?

Comment: you should make sure you add the extension and not rely on the browser to do it for you. We don't do this for you based on the mime type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, as per the comments at the top, the solution was to add the file extension onto the filename attribute in BlobInfo. I didn't initially realize this was necessary since Chrome automatically added the file extension when downloading.